# Opening a hyperlink generated dynamically with a string command

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, hyperlink

Backstory,

So I am working on a personal assistant program and all my voice commands are translated into strings for parsing.

I have set up the ability to search Google and display the results in a text block as hyperlinks.

Now I want to be able to set up the ability to open these links with speech(string commands). So far I have the following.

This bit allows me to search using the Google Custom Search API with a custom "GoogleSearch" class.

```
public void search_google(string query) //Google Searching
    {
        #region link strings
        string result_1 = "";
        string result_2 = "";
        string result_3 = "";
        string result_4 = "";
        string result_5 = "";
        string result_6 = "";
        string result_7 = "";
        string result_8 = "";
        string result_9 = "";
        string result_10 = "";
        #endregion

        GoogleSearch search = new GoogleSearch()
        {
            Key = "{apikey}",
            CX = "{cxkey}"
        };
        search.SearchCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            tab_control.SelectedIndex = 2;
            int p = 1;
            search_results.Text = String.Empty;
            foreach (Item i in b.Response.Items)
            {

                Hyperlink hyperLink = new Hyperlink()
                {
                    NavigateUri = new Uri(i.Link)
                };
                hyperLink.Inlines.Add(i.Title);
                hyperLink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
                hyperLink.Name = "result_" + p;
                //search_results.Inlines.Add(hyperLink.Name);
                search_results.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                search_results.Inlines.Add(hyperLink);

                search_results.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                search_results.Inlines.Add(i.Snippet);
                search_results.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                search_results.Inlines.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                p++;

            };
        };
        search.Search(query);
    }
```

It outputs my results in a series of hyperlinks and text snippets into a text block that I set up on the main window. The search process is triggered by my input parser which looks for the keywords "search" or "Google".

The next step would be the input parser checking for keyword "result" to look for the hyperlink to open. Here is the unfinished code for that.

```
if ((Input.Contains("result") || Input.Contains("Result")) && tab_control.TabIndex == 2)
        {
            int result_number = 0;
            switch(result_number)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (Input.Contains("first") || Input.Contains("1st"))
                    {
                        // open hyperlink with name property result_1
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                        // additional cases added up to 10 with similar syntax for parsing.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a hyperlink in the default browser using:

```
Process.Start(myHyperlink);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, it seems you are having trouble accessing `result_1` (etc.).

You define `result_1` as a variable local to the method `search_google()`

```
public void search_google(string query) //Google Searching
{
    #region link strings
    string result_1 = "";
```

That means `result_1` is only visible within that method.

Your `if` and `switch` statements do not appear to be part of `search_google()`, so they can never see `result_1`.  If those statements are in a different method, you can work around that issue by moving `result_1` to the class level (outside of `search_google()`).

ON a site note, rather than defining ten individual result strings, you probably want to use  an array of strings or a list of strings.

Comment: in my code though for some reason I cannot access the hyperlinks in other parts of my program. It suggests to me that it is because they are not public but the method is set to public. Am I missing something?

Comment: By `cannot access` do you mean that you get a compiler error?  If so, what exactly is the error?

Comment: It actually seems to be a problem with the fact that the links are dynamically created when the process is run. Before I search something the hyperlinks don't exist. So visual studio is telling me that they don't exist. So how can I get it to allow me to specify code to open links that do not yet exist?

Error is "The name 'result_1' does not exist in the current context.
But it does exist once the search is run.

Comment: `Visual Studio is telling me that they don't exist` - how exactly?  You're not providing enough context for me to know what exactly you are doing, or what exactly is not working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, clarified in edit. 
Error is "The name 'result_1' does not exist in the current context. But it does exist once the search is run.

Comment: Edited my answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: So I created an array using private string[] results; and then adding the string values to a list. Then converting the list into the array "results"

Comment: - Got cut off on my last comment. This returns an error when I try to navigate to results[0] the error is "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Eric J. Thanks for the idea of a list to array conversion. I had to declare the list in the main section of the program and then convert it to a string within the input parsing code to get it to work right.